# HTML table using Javascript from JSON data -error: cannot read porperties of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to create a HTML table from JSON data using Javascript. My issue lies within the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` So I'm wondering how this can be fixed in order to work correctly.

JS code:

```
const requestUrl6 = 'https://api.npoint.io/1cae29b5fc8900f6cc5a';
const requestJSON6 = async url => {

  const response6 = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  const keys = Object.keys(response6);
  for (let keyIndex = 0; keyIndex < keys.length; keyIndex++){
  const limit6 = Math.max(...Object.keys(response6[keys[keyIndex]][0].expenses)) + 1;
  for(let index6 = 0; index6 < limit6; index6++)
  {
      let newRow6 = rowTemplate6.cloneNode(true);
      newRow6.id = '';
      newRow6.querySelector('.Expenses6').innerHTML = response6.expenses[index6];
      newRow6.querySelector('.Date6').innerHTML = response6.dt_posted[index6];
      newRow6.querySelector('.Purpose6').innerHTML = response6.description[index6];
      rowTemplate6.parentNode.appendChild(newRow6);
  }
  rowTemplate6.parentNode.removeChild(rowTemplate6); }
}
requestJSON6(requestUrl6);
```

The issue is in this line of code:  `const limit6 = Math.max(...Object.keys(response6[keys[keyIndex]][0].expenses)) + 1;`

HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="content-table_page6" style="color: rgb(16, 16, 16); font-size: 15px;">
    <tr class="toptable6">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Expenses</th>
        <th>Lobying Activities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id='rowTemplate6'>
      <td class='Expenses6' style="text-align:center; font-size: 10px;"></td>
      <td class='Date6' style="text-align:center; font-size: 10px;"></td>
      <td class='Purpose6' style="text-align:center; font-size: 10px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>


  <script src="AAPL_Corporate_lobbying.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

however, in the issue code line you gave were no errors for me. Instead, it threw me errors in this

```
newRow6.querySelector('.Expenses6').innerHTML = response6.expenses[index6];
```

line. It looks like you forgot to add the sub-keys. You tried to access JSON that would look like this:

```
{
    "expenses": [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
    ]
}
```

You have to add the other keys to go further in the JSON object. You can do this by replacing

```
response6.expenses[index6]
```

with

```
response6[keys[keyIndex]][0]["expenses"][index6]
```

I've created a Pen with the working code: https://codepen.io/celharding/pen/KKeYNxY

Comment: Amazing thank you! :) I was assuming it was that line I initially asked as it was the most recent line i added to try make it work